Good approach to compare enrichment of interactions across groups?
I have a question about the best metric to compute so that I can compare the enrichment of interactions between two "cohorts" of graphs.
Each "individual" in my dataset is composed of a network of labeled, interacting nodes in an undirected graph. Within each individual, I start by determining whether each possible pair of labels (e.g. "red" and "green") interacts randomly, or whether there is an enrichment/depletion of interactions for that pair. Random interactions should have a value close to zero, less interactions than expected (depletion) would have a negative value, and more interactions than expected (enrichment) would have a positive value. I want to compute a value that's "normalized" in some way to the frequency of "red" and "green" nodes--an individual with a lot of red and green should be expected to have a lot of interactions between red & green, and would need to have a higher number of interactions to be enriched.
These "individuals" are also divided into groups (let's say "responders" and "non-responders"). I would like to know (this is the real crux), for each possible pair of labels, whether there is a difference in enrichment/depletion between the groups.
Let me try to illustrate with an example: for each individual, I compute whether red and green nodes interact more or less than would be expected for random interactions. I then want to compare this interaction across responders and non-responders: is the interaction between red and green nodes overall more enriched in responders? Or overall less enriched?
For the first part (individual-level enrichment) I've tried a permutation based approach. For each permutation, I randomly shuffle the labels within that individual's graph and then count the number of interactions for each pair of labels.
Is there a metric I can derive from this kind of permutation that would be appropriate to use for comparing between cohorts? E.g. if I compute a z-score from this (observed number of interactions - mean # observed in permutations / sd of # observed in permutations), would it be appropriate to treat that as an individual's datapoint for a two-sample t-test?
Or is there another approach I should be using instead of permutation to determine the individual-level enrichments, which would more naturally lend itself to subsequent comparison between groups of individuals?
